# Date and time managing when you have global users on application

Tags: php, timezone

I am working on an application where we have users from around the globe. We have some condition where particular things are only available to user when clock hits a certain time. Which means user will be able to see a report or something like that after 7:00 AM only. My approach is that I am storing a timezone specified by users and once they login I am setting the default timzone in config file to that value. Basically using a php function date_default_timezone_set() function. 
1) is that a right approach to deal with timezone.

Any other better solution/suggestions to deal with timezone in PHP ?

Comment: This is too broad, as you are asking multiple questions.  Also, most of your concerns have already been asked.  Please search before asking, and then only ask *specific* questions.  Also, please define your requirements better.  (Consider that it's only 7:00am for one minute, then it's 7:01am.)

Comment: Thanks for your response Matt. I tried to be specific in my edit. With 7:00 am I mean, any time after 7:00 am on that particular day.